# How to get each total from database?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

How to Write Query to Getting Below Output?

In database:

Table 1:

```
id Company_accountNo
1   123
2   235 
3   456
```

Table 2:

```
id cheque_no company_accnopky amount
1   258        1               100
2   963        1               200
3   147        2               500
4   148        3               800
5   852        2               300
```

How get output like this?

```
Account_no   Total_Amount   No_of_Cheque
123           300               2
235           800               2
456           800               1
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What dbms are you using? Could you also add what you have tried so far?

Comment: MSSQL/MySQL syntax: `select company_acc_no, count(1) as no_of_cheque, sum(amount) as total_amount from table1 inner join table2 on table1.company_acc_np = table2.company_acc_no group by company_acc_no`

Comment: I want hibernate Query it make error query syntax exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
SELECT
T1.Company_accountNo As Account_no,
sum(T2.Amount) As Total_Amount,
count(T1.Company_accountNo) AS No_of_Cheque  
FROM Table1 T1 Inner Join Table2 T2 ON T1.id = T2.company_accnopky 
Group By T1.Company_accountNo
```

I Think You are Missing **Group By**

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.Company_accountNo Account_no,
  SUM(b.amount) Total_Amount,
  COUNT(*) No_of_Cheque
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b
ON a.id=b.company_accnopky
GROUP BY a.Company_accountNo
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
select t1.Company_accountNo, SUM(t2.amount) as amount, count(t2.cheque_no) as cheque_no
from table1 t1, table2 t2
where t1.id=t2.company_accnopky
group by t1.Company_accountNo
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
select 
    a.Company_accountNo as Account_no, 
    SUM(b.amount) as Total_Amount, 
    COUNT(*) No_of_Cheque
from 
    tbl1 a inner join tbl2 b on a.id=b.company_accnopky
group by a.Company_accountNo
```